# command to use on windows openssh to download file from Ubuntu server

Tags: windows, openssh

I am using OPENSSH Client ("`terminal`") on windows, and I would like to download a file from an Ubuntu server TO my windows file system; is there a command to use?

Comment: I have no idea about openssh on Windows (as I am an Ubuntu user and this site is specific to Ubuntu and usually doesn't deal with Windows questions). But: _Do you have a command named `scp`?_

Comment: What do you mean "OPENSSH Client"? What is the name of this app? Maybe useful for you will be WinSCP.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Winscp to download files from ubuntu and upload to ubuntu.
you can download winscp from - https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.15.1-Setup.exe

Comment: it is similar to filezilla....thanks for the effort; I had thought that you can download a file directly from CMD (ssh) in windows from ubuntu with some specific commands...